# Image not displaying in MongoDB using php

Tags: php, mongodb

Im a complete newbie in MongoDB and php, and my problem is that an image stored in my location database is not displaying. I have a test code that inserts all my data including my image name. this image name will be used to access the image stored in the same database.

here's my insert data code

```
 <?php
try {
    // open connection to MongoDB server

    $conn = new Mongo('localhost');

    //access database

    $db = $conn->location;

    //access collection
    $collection = $db->loc;

    // insert a new document
    $filename = "102120140913290.jpg";
    $data = array(
        'name' => 'Butuan',
        'latitude'=> 8.9576751,
        'longitude' => 125.5963283,
        'imagename' => $filename
        );

    $collection->insert($data);
    echo 'Inserted document withy ID:' . $data['_id'] . '<br/>';

    $img = $db->getGridFS();
    $path = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mysite\\upload\\";


    $storedfile =   $img->storeFile($path . $filename,
             array("metadata" => array("filename" => $filename),
             "filename" => $filename));

    echo 'Stored file ID:' . $storedfile;

} catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
  die('Error connecting to MongoDB server');
} catch (MongoException $e) {
  die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

and here is my get image code

```
<?php

    try{

        $conn = new Mongo('localhost');
        $db = $conn->location;
        $collection = $db->loc;

        $cursor = $collection->find();
        $imgname;
        echo $cursor->count(). 'document(s) found. <br/>';

        foreach($cursor as $obj){
            $imgname = $obj['imagename'];
        }


        $gridFS = $db->getGridFS();
        $image = $gridFS->findOne($imgname);

        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        echo $image->getBytes();

    } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
      die('Error connecting to MongoDB server');
    } catch (MongoException $e) {
      die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    ?>
```

all I get is a broken Image. Please help.. thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checking a couple of things

you should be using "new MongoClient" as "new Mongo" has been depricated.

Try replacing the following segment of code:

```
$gridFS = $db->getGridFS();
$image = $gridFS->findOne($imgname);
$imageFile = $image->getBytes();

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($imageFile));
ob_clean();
echo $imageFile;
```

Also look at the storeUpload function http://php.net/manual/en/mongogridfs.storeupload.php

Comment: whats the ob_clean stands for?

Comment: I believe it stands for "ouput buffer".